# Spring Boot OAuth2 Authorization Server with 2 step login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to set up a small micro-service style project using Spring Boot and OAuth2 with JWT.

Here's the flow I would like:

```
-> user clicks login and is taken to login page on Auth server
-> user logs in
-> user selects or creates a profile
-> login returns with the selected profile as part of the JWT
```

I know how to populate additional data in the JWT token but where I'm lost is the 2-step login.

Previously in monolithic Spring with traditional Spring Security I would do something like have a filter check for the presence of a cookie containing the current profile and if not present redirect to the "select/make a profile" screen.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find some inspiration [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2).
This repository contains example projects containing some common use cases for OAuth2.